# Temporary is still binded to reference, when casted to reference type first

Tags: c++

When compiling some weird code for better C++ standard understanding, I met an example, where I'm not actually sure what is happening. Consider a simple class, which make debug output, when it constructed or destructed:

```
struct C {
    C() { cout << "Constructed\t" << this << "\n"; }
    C(const C& source) = delete;
    C(C&&) = delete;
    ~C() { cout << "Destructed\t" << this << "\n"; }
};
```

Now the code, which behaviour I don't understand:

```
int main()
{
    const C& r = static_cast<const C&>(C());
    cout << "Next line" << endl;
}
```

The output is (tried it with gcc and clang):

```
Constructed 0x7fff6d6ebe60  
Next line  
Destructed  0x7fff6d6ebe60
```

So, as u can see here, temporary object is binded to reference even when it casted to reference type first. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried to answer it myself and this is my thoughts:

1. `C()` creates a temporary prvalue
2. For `static_cast` 5.2.9p4 is applicated:

   > Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

   So a temporary reference is created and the result of `static_cast` expression is lvalue
3. What happens next and why lifetime of temporary is extended? Is it something like a temporary binded to temporary reference, which itself binded to other reference?

P.S. Also tried this (add an address-taking and derefernce operators):

```
int main()
{
    const C& r = *&static_cast<const C&>(C());
    cout << "Next line" << endl;
}
```

And gcc output is still:

```
Constructed 0x7fffa1c50157
Next line
Destructed  0x7fffa1c50157
```

while clang destroy temporary before "Next line" in this case:

```
Constructed 0x7fff3374ab60
Destructed  0x7fff3374ab60
Next line
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to look at clauses 12.2/4 and 12.2/5 of Standard:

> 4. There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array. If
>      the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default
>      argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.
> 5. The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>      bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>      for the lifetime of the reference except: ...

this should answer your question - why the lifetime is extended.

Comment: Of course, I read it, but here `C()` temporary doesn't bind to reference `r`, first it is casted to reference type. For example, we can replace a cast with some function, which returns `const C&` and semanticly it will be the same initialization for `r` as with cast.

Comment: @Bevel I don't see the problem. Your temporary reference (from the `static_cast` is bound to the temporary `C`. Then the reference `r` is bound to the same temporary `C`.

Comment: @BevelLemelisk with or without casting assembly output is same: http://goo.gl/EaQswe

Comment: What is confusing me here, it is a fact that our reference's initialization is semanticly the same as `const C& r = f();`, where `f()` is `const C& f();`. In both this cases, the right part is lvalue of `const C&`, where in classical `const C& r = C();` the right part is prvalue of `C`, so I was expecting the same behaviour as in case with function (address is given, just store it and doesn't care).